# Why does Blender render black?

Tags: rendering

I have downloaded a .blend file that contained a pistol model.
Also, it contained a light.

The rendering was set to "Blender Game".

Since the default blender rendering doesn't require a light in the scene, and since I wanted to get rid of the light, I deleted it.

Since then the view shows a black weapon model:

[image]

I have set the rendering mode to "Blender Render", hoping that this would restore the default lighting, but it didn't help.

As one can see, the default blender scene also doesn't have a light, and it still renders fine:

[image]

How could I set the default blender rendering in this case?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: You can try to readd the lamp, maybe the model has no textures or materials. Does the sczene have any light as background?

Comment: I have edited my post to show that the model does have textures / materials. Also, the scene doesn't have any light component. In my post I have also added a screenshot of the default scene. In this screenshot one can see that there's no light component, and still the cube renders fine / not black.

Comment: Try to copy it over to a new file to see if this is file specific, if it still is black, there is something wrong with the texture, of its not black then your old scene was missing a light. Otherwise I have no reasonable explanation but a missing illumination. If possible you could upload the blend file to let us see what's wrong

Comment: This looks like a problem with terminology. The scene shown on the second screenshot isn't rendered. It is shown in Solid mode where light isn't taken into account at all. You can delete light and still preview everything just the same. In Blender game you also have Solid shading mode (or texture/material). It would maybe help to answer your question if you tell why do you want to get rid of light and what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just click on the toolbar on the left > Create > Lamp: Point. In Blender Render, unlit objects show completely black. Make sure you move the lamp around (G) so that the pistol is illuminated by the light.

EDIT: It looks like you are in the Material view. Switch to Solid view (on the bottom toolbar)

Comment: I don't want to have a lamp in my scene. Also, it shouldn't be necessary, should it? When I create a new scene in Blender, there's no lamp in it, and the cube is still lit and not black.

Comment: The cube is not black because the world background is not black but gray, this illuminates the cube, in your sczene its black.

Comment: Could you tell me how to make the world background gray / not black?

Comment: He's not even in Render mode. Texture mode needs no lights, so there is something wrong with his material setup.

Comment: Switching to Solid Mode resolved the problem for me. When I added a light, I could also switch to Texture Mode again, and it would show up nicely.